# Find device information when Activation Lock is activated

Tags: ipad, icloud, activation-lock

Is there a way to find the time and date of when Activation Lock was activated on an iPad? Also, can I find the IMEI and serial of the iPad? My iPad has few iCloud IDs and I know just 1 ID. What can I do to get useful information about which iCloud ID caused the iPad activation lock and when?

Comment: start at http://iforgot.apple.com If it's had the activation lock set, then you first need to persuade Apple that it's actually your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The activation lock screen will display the first few characters and domain name of the Apple ID used to lock the device. This should be sufficient information for you to tell which Apple ID is being requested.